# Equivalence between Photoshop effects and GD Library or ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, photoshop

I have created a magazine layout in Photoshop and I want to use GD or ImageMagick to generate custom magazine covers dynamically, based on what an user input, for that I used a few effects on Photoshop, basicaly with a specific "Drop Shadow" effect over text layers.

I found some drop shadow over GD/ImageMagick tutorials, but none of them was so complete about which setting is similar to the photoshop ones, for example, I have one drop shadow with this settings:

```
Blend Mode: Multiply 
Opacity: 75%
Angle: 120º
Distance: 1px
Spread: 3%
Size: 5px
```

Is there a way to recreate that on code?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What were the results of your experiment? How would you like the solution to be different from your results?

Comment: I followed this tutorial http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Adding-Drop-Shadows-with-PHP/ but the result was way different then my PSD because I couldn't find anywhere options similar to Photoshop ones

Comment: Post your code.  People will probably help you.  You're not going to get much without posting code though.

Comment: As Lee said example images would help; I for one do not have photoshop. Imagemagick shadow options are -shadow percent-opacity{xsigma}{+-}x{+-}y{%} and I would say that you will not be able to reproduce the Photoshop options exactly.